# How to get notifications with the github api using go

Tags: go, github-api

I am trying to write a go program to connect to the github api and to get notifications on my account. I can get repos and infos on the user pretty easily but I am having a hard time getting notifications, even if I have notification on my account, the array is always empty. Does someone knows what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance !

Here is my code :

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"

    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

/**
 * this function is used to get the repositories of the client
 */
func getRepo(client *github.Client) []*github.Repository {
    ctx := context.Background()

    repos, _, err := client.Repositories.List(ctx, "", nil)

    check(err)

    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", github.Stringify(repos))

    return repos
}

/**
 * this function is used to get Authentification using a oauth token
 */
func getAuth() *github.Client {
    ctx := context.Background()
    // put your own OAUTH_TOKEN
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{AccessToken: "OAUTH_TOKEN"})

    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)
    client := github.NewClient(tc)

    return client
}

/**
 * this function is used to get notification on the client's account
 */
func getNotif(client *github.Client) []*github.Notification {
    ctx := context.Background()

    notifs, resp, err := client.Activity.ListRepositoryNotifications(ctx, "AlexandreMazgaj", "task_app", nil)

    fmt.Printf("Status code of the response: %d\n", resp.StatusCode)
    check(err)

    return notifs
}

func main() {
    // first we get authentification
    client := getAuth()
    // then we get the notifications
    notifs := getNotif(client)

    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", github.Stringify(notifs))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, the program is working, the problem was on my side, I did not enable notifications on web in my github settings.